# Is there a way to pass CFDI and SAT information through a Sales order in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I would like to pass sales orders with their CFDI code already in them so that they don't have to be manually put in when they are billed. I tried doing it through csv imports since I saw that the fields were present there but it did not work, I also tried doing it by importing sales invoices but those didn't work either. is there some way this could be done?

Comment: What is the Tax engine in your Netsuite account? Have you set up a nexus for Mexico?
If you don't have tax codes for MX (setup / accounting/tax codes and set country filter to Mexico) then you can't import them.

Comment: yeah, it's a Mexican account, all the codes are already configured, but I tried importing a couple of orders and the cfdi was not carried over